# Black hole properties

Tags: black-hole

Black holes are things with immense gravity.Inside black holes gravity is much stronger than any other fundamental forces.But is strong enough to overcome Pauli repulsion?

Comment: Some of the answers to [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14185/24157) discuss Pauli repulsion in black holes, maybe of relevance here?

Comment: As indicated in the question to the linked answer, "Yes" the force is strong enough to overcome Pauli repulsion.

Comment: James K gravity is not a force.It is a property of space time.